# Find an example of an infinite dimensional vector space for which the following conditions of matrix convergence are not equivalent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

I need to find an example of linear operators $A_{n}$ and $A$ on an infinite dimensional vector space with norm $\| \cdot\|$ such that the following conditions are *not* equivalent:

(i) $\|A_n -A\| \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty$;

(ii) $|A_{n}x-Ax| \to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty$ for each fixed $x$;

(iii) $|\langle A_{n}x,y\rangle - \langle Ax,y\rangle| \to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty$ for each fixed $x$ and $y$.

These *are* equivalent for any finite dimensional vector space, though perhaps one or two examples will show that the implications do not follow for an infinite dimensional vector space.

Comment: My apologies! I believe that I just need to find an example where the conditions aren't equivalent for any normed infinite dimensional vector space. I'll remove the reference to the previously-defined norm (which is used in other parts of the question).

Answer (score 1):

Let $V=\oplus_{j=1}^\infty \Bbb R$ with the operator norm. Let $A$ be the identity function, and let $A_n$ be the identity on the first $n$ coordinates, and zero after that.

These fit the second two conditions, but the norm of the difference is always 1, so it fails the first condition.

Comment: To clarify, is $V$ the vector space of vectors with in infinitude of real-valued coordinates?

Comment: @Exp5LogMingus The direct sum of countably many copies of $\Bbb R$. You can also think of it as the subset of functions from $\Bbb N\to \Bbb R$ which are zero except in a finite set. Does that clarify everything?

Comment: I believe so, yes.